# go build -buildvcs does not insert vcs.revision buildinfo

Tags: go

This question poses problems that are distinct from those discussed here: [How do you read debug VCS version info from a Go 1.18 binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71642366/how-do-you-read-debug-vcs-version-info-from-a-go-1-18-binary)

I am having trouble getting `go build -buildvcs=true` to insert correct version information when building executables out of a git repo that has the following structure:

`go version go1.18.4 linux/amd64`

in `project`:

```
go.mod
cmd/exe1/main.go
cmd/exe2/main.go
pkg/pkg1/...
pkg/pkg2/...
```

(1) If I `cd project;go build -buildvcs=true -o /tmp/exe1 cmd/exe1/main.go` then the BuildInfo included in the exe includes `Deps` entries for all the dependencies of all the packages, but there is no embedded `Setting` with key `vcs.revision`, and the `Dep` entry for the module named in go.mod is `(devel)`. I guess this latter issue is related to how to specify versions for modules, which I have not yet looked into, and therefore I assume it's using a default value.

(2) If I `cd project/cmd/exe1;go build -buildvcs=true -o /tmp/exe1` (leaving out any relative path specifying what to build) then the BuildInfo included in the exe does NOT include `Deps` entries but DOES include the `vcs.revision`

Questions:
Is there any way to get both `Deps` and `vcs.revision` into BuildInfo?
Is this directory structure ok? The documentation for this stuff is not in "reference" format, and many important details are spread out throughout all of the tutorials and howtos. Quite frustrating to get to the bottom of these behaviors.

It seems to me go should embed a `vcs.revision` whenever generating an executable, but before I open a bug, I wanted to get community feedback on whether this is expected behavior when specifying a relative target on the command line. I've seen that that can be an issue in general, with go build.

Any pointers to the right place to read a comprehensive guide about this would be great.